# Android center Bitmap in ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I have got an ImageView, which shows a Bitmap. When I set my Bitmap to the ImageView, it is not centered. I also tried to set scaleType to center, centerCrop, centerInside.

That's my ImageView in Layout:

```
    android:id="@+id/xyz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.03"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

**EDIT:**
that is the code which resizes the bitmap:

```
private void scaleImage() {
    Bitmap bitmap = getHostPage().getBackgroundDrawing();

    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int bounding = dpToPx(250);
    float xScale = ((float) bounding) / width;
    float yScale = ((float) bounding) / height;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(xScale, yScale);

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    width = scaledBitmap.getWidth(); 
    height = scaledBitmap.getHeight(); 
    BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap);

    getHostPage().setBackgroundDrawing(result.getBitmap());
    
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) drawView.getLayoutParams(); 
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    drawView.setLayoutParams(params);

}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    float density = hostPage.getHostActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float)dp * density);
}
```

[image: bitmap]

Comment: android:gravity="center_horizontal" or android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: you can also use a FrameLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
```

Comment: <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"> <com.numberatank.Utils.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" /></RelativeLayout>

Comment: not working with this imageview. I have tried with this in relative view but bitmap set left side not coming in center

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your image view xml code :

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

I think it may help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:id="@+id/xyz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.03"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```